# Change state of an object in Kotlin with immutable properties

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin we have this notion of immutable properties.

I once heard that in functional programming, state should not be changed. I have been thinking about this in the context of domain models.

Let's say we have a `Person` class (please don't mind this very silly and unrealistic example).

```
class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, val age: Int)
```

Everything property is immutable, which is nice.

Now someone comes along and asks to replace the first name. So I create a function that can do this.

```
fun replaceFirstName(person: Person, newFirstName: String): Person {
    return Person(newFirstName, person.lastName, person.age)
}
```

Now this looks really ugly to my eyes. In this case there are only 3 properties, of which one should be replaced. But you can probably imagine what this would look like in larger domain classes.

The easy thing would be to just replace the `val` with a `var`, but then the whole intention of immutability is gone.

I'm looking for something like this (it does throw an error since there is no copy function):

```
fun replaceName(person: Person, newFirstName: String): Person {
    return person.copy { firstName = newFirstName }
}
```

Is there a nice and concise way to do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kotlin has a concept of [Data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html), which has `copy` function you need. So if you'll declare your class as:

```
data class Person(val firstName:String, val lastName:String, val age:Int)
```

You'll be able to use this function. Also it will generate `equals()/hashCode/toString()` for you.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested, you can also do this using a [lens](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/optics/lens/).

It's probably not necessary for an easy case, but when you have very deep objects that need just one property changed, it can be useful:

```
import arrow.optics.*

data class Person(val firstName:String, val lastName:String, val age:Int)

val firstNameLens: Lens<Person, String> = Lens(
    get = { person -> person.firstName },
    set = { newFirstName-> { person -> person.copy(firstName = newFirstName) } }
)
```

Then you can do:

```
val doe = Person("John", "Doe", 30)
firstNameLens.set(doe, "Henry")
//output: Person(firstName = "Henry", lastName = "Doe", age = 30)
```

and:

```
val doe = Person("John", "Doe", 30)
firstNameLens.get(doe)
//output: "John"
```

and:

```
val doe = Person("John", "Doe", 30)
firstNameLens.modify(doe, { it + "ny" })
//output: Person(firstName = "Johnny", lastName = "Doe", age = 30)
```

Comment: I'm very interested. Thanks for sharing.